# aplay: device_list:268: No sound card found

Tags: 14.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

I tried all other commands listed in the other answers but still the commands are not working on my Lenovo IdeaPad 310-15ISK on which Ubuntu 14.04 is installed.
The aplay -l command shows no soundcard found error.
I tried aptitude command and all others, still...
The sound is not mute but still nothing is happening with the other commands.

Comment: Try newer Ubuntu (16.04 or 16.10), 14.04 Alsa driver may be outdated

Comment: Is the audio chipset internal or external? What's the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio`